# Why are System V message queues conforming POSIX NOT called POSIX message queues?

Tags: posix, system-v

I know that there are (at least) two types of message queues: System V message queues and POSIX message queue. To my surprise, the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgget.2.html) also says that the **msgget** system call for System V message queues, for example,

CONFORMS TO

> POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008, SVr4.

Since System V message queques conformed to POSIX, why did the POSIX organization bother to invent so-called POSIX message queues that were different from System V message queues?

Comment: Side note: There's an excellent overview of the historical development of Unix branches in Michael Kerrisk's [The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/index.html), which is a very recommandable supplement to the man pages and would be a good start for you to dig into the details.

Answer (score 0):

System V message queues predate POSIX. They were adopted by POSIX probably over a decade after they were introduced in System V Unix. The "POSIX message queues" were introduced relatively recently and were invented because of dislike (at least by some) of the System V implementation.